# Error 9 with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have a small problem with my code.
It keeps failing with a problem

```
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim kSheet As Worksheet

Set kSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("customer")
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

kSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = x.Text
kSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = y.Text
```

What im trying to do is simple: i have 2 buttons on sheet 1. This sheet also needs to stay active all the time. With a button it brings up a userform, where you can input data. This data will get inserted into sheet "customer".

EDIT: It now gives me an error 9 with setting kSheet

Could anyone help me out?

Kind regards

Comment: BIRDSVIEW: Try this `emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(kSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1`

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to find the emptyrow on the sheet it meant to be on. But i have a new problem: kSheet stays "Nothing" if i run it in debug mode. It also returns an error 9

Comment: Is your sheet called "customer" actually on the same workbook and is it really called "customer"?

Comment: It is really called customer, and not sheet2. It's in the same excel document (if that's what you meant with workbook)

Comment: There has to be a referencing problem, you could test that just adding line `debug.print ActiveWorkbook.Name` before you set the value of kSheet.. Check if the reference to the workbook on immediate window is correct.

Comment: Yes it is the same: debug.print gives "SalesApp.xlsm" and my excel document is also called "SalesApp.xlsm"

Comment: Try `Msgbox ActiveSheet.Name` while you are on the "customer" sheet.

Comment: So that should not be the cause of your problem, I would do the correction siddharth suggested and double check the name of the sheet. There is nothing else that could be causing the problem at least that I can think of..-

Comment: If you have crashed a sufficient number of times there could be rogue variables pointing to the *customers* worksheet. Save the workbook and exit Excel. Rebooting entirely is not a bad idea. When you get back into your project remember to add `Set kSheet = Nothing` at the end of the procedure and possibly put it into an error control cleanup area named `FallThrough:` and use `On Error GoTo FallThrough` at the start of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i've found the problem. I actually changed the Sheet1, Sheet2 etc. to customer, but not the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (name) of the sheet was customer, but the actual name was sheet2.

Correct code is:

```
Set kSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
```